# Finding sets of files matching the same substring

Tags: python

I have a set of files with the following type of name:
`soil_moisture_2015090T043000_sm_global.tif`
`soil_moisture_2015090T133000_sm_global.tif`
`soil_moisture_2015090T163000_sm_global.tif`
`soil_moisture_2015091T073000_sm_global.tif`
`soil_moisture_2015091T223000_sm_global.tif`
`soil_moisture_2015092T013000_sm_global.tif`

The first three files have the same date `2015090` and the next three files have the same date `2015092`. How can I find all sets of files in the directory that share the same date in the name? I know how to do this for a substring match, but not sure how to do it when the substring itself is changing.

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob('/dir/soil_moisture_*_sm_global.tif'):
    print file
```

Answer (score 2):

if you're open to using pandas, you could extract the date, remove the date and then use a groupby operation.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

files = Path('/dir/to_files').glob('*your_pattern*')

print(files)

[PosixPath('soil_moisture_2015090T043000_sm_global.tif'),
 PosixPath('soil_moisture_2015090T133000_sm_global.tif'),
 PosixPath('soil_moisture_2015090T163000_sm_global.tif'),
 PosixPath('soil_moisture_2015091T073000_sm_global.tif'),
 PosixPath('soil_moisture_2015091T223000_sm_global.tif'),
 PosixPath('soil_moisture_2015092T013000_sm_global.tif')]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(files)

df['dt'] = df[0].astype(str).str.extract('_(\d+)').astype(int)


df['unique_file'] =  df[0].astype(str).str.replace('_(\d+T\d+)','',regex=True)

print(df)

                                            0       dt                  unique_file
0  soil_moisture_2015090T043000_sm_global.tif  2015090  soil_moisture_sm_global.tif
1  soil_moisture_2015090T133000_sm_global.tif  2015090  soil_moisture_sm_global.tif
2  soil_moisture_2015090T163000_sm_global.tif  2015090  soil_moisture_sm_global.tif
3  soil_moisture_2015091T073000_sm_global.tif  2015091  soil_moisture_sm_global.tif
4  soil_moisture_2015091T223000_sm_global.tif  2015091  soil_moisture_sm_global.tif
5  soil_moisture_2015092T013000_sm_global.tif  2015092  soil_moisture_sm_global.tif



df.groupby(['dt','unique_file'])[0].count()

dt       unique_file
2015090  soil_moisture_sm_global.tif    3
2015091  soil_moisture_sm_global.tif    2
2015092  soil_moisture_sm_global.tif    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```